# Liferay 6.2 GA3 doesn't displaying articles when being configured with SOLR search engine

Tags: solr, liferay

I have integrated SOLR with Liferay 6.2 using the https://web.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/30365680 plugin and have the following behaviour

1. I do a reindex in Liferay and see that SOLR index is ok. Do some search queries and data are being returned
2. I setup Asset publisher to display content from some category but search results not being displayed. If I see the solr.log and the query passed to solr from liferay, and pass it to solr ui in the query tab results are being displayed in solr ui. So it seems that liferay doesn't communicate correctly with SOLR

below you can find part of log where is clear that no hits come from solr

```
INFO  - 2018-08-02 11:27:30.075; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=%2B(%2B(assetCategoryIds:15508+assetCategoryIds:15507+assetCategoryIds:15506+assetCategoryIds:15509+assetCategoryIds:15510+assetCategoryIds:15511+assetCategoryIds:15512+assetCategoryIds:15515+assetCategoryIds:15517+assetCategoryIds:15516+assetCategoryIds:15513+assetCategoryIds:15514)+%2B((%2B(%2B(entryClassName:com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle)+%2B(userId:10159+(roleId:10163)))+%2B(status:0)+%2B(head:true)))+%2B(%2B(groupId:10182)+%2B(scopeGroupId:10182)))+%2B(visible:true)+%2BcompanyId:10155&wt=javabin&version=2&rows=0} hits=0 status=0 QTime=0

INFO  - 2018-08-02 11:27:30.077; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/select params={fl=*,score&sort=publishDate_sortable+desc,localized_title_el_GR_sortable+asc&start=0&q=%2B(%2B(assetCategoryIds:15508+assetCategoryIds:15507+assetCategoryIds:15506+assetCategoryIds:15509+assetCategoryIds:15510+assetCategoryIds:15511+assetCategoryIds:15512+assetCategoryIds:15515+assetCategoryIds:15517+assetCategoryIds:15516+assetCategoryIds:15513+assetCategoryIds:15514)+%2B((%2B(%2B(entryClassName:com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle)+%2B(userId:10159+(roleId:10163)))+%2B(status:0)+%2B(head:true)))+%2B(%2B(groupId:10182)+%2B(scopeGroupId:10182)))+%2B(visible:true)+%2BcompanyId:10155&facet.limit=-1&wt=javabin&version=2&rows=0} hits=0 status=0 QTime=0
```

The article will be displayed only if I manually update the article in Liferay

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: If you issue the same query against SOLR, do you get results?

Comment: Yes. that is the strange

Comment: Did you change the solr properties inside of the marketplace plugin to match you solr host?

Answer (score 0):

You hint at just why it is not working...

> The article will be displayed only if I manually update the article in
>   Liferay.

To me this indicates the following:

1. You are programmatically creating the entity or, even worse, you have an external process which is writing directly into the Liferay database.
2. Whichever one of these you are doing, you are not doing it completely/correctly.  If you run the same query against SOLR that Liferay is executing, I'm guessing you too would not get any hits back.
3. When you edit manually in Liferay, when you save the article Liferay is saving it correctly so it indexes correctly and therefore satisfies the SOLR criteria and appears in the search results.